# error after upgrading, how do i fix this

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg, dependencies

```
dpkg: error processing package libfwupdplugin5:amd64 (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of fwupd:
 fwupd depends on libfwupdplugin5 (= 1.7.9-1~22.04.1); however:
  Package libfwupdplugin5:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package fwupd (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup erro
r from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 libfwupdplugin5:amd64
 fwupd
```

Comment: The fix is exactly what it suggests: Reinstall the package which is "in a very bad inconsistent state".

Comment: Thanks but how do i do that

Comment: You do it by running: `sudo apt install --reinstall libfwupdplugin5`

Comment: Thank you that worked

Comment: I've turned it into an answer that you can accept later. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message suggests:

```
dpkg: error processing package libfwupdplugin5:amd64 (--configure):
  package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
  reinstall it before attempting configuration
```

You should reinstall the package in very bad inconsistent state:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall libfwupdplugin5
```